# How can I use .htaccess to automatically chmod a folder?

Tags: apache, .htaccess

I'm looking at this article http://www.jwrmedia.com/lessons/htaccess/automatic-chmod

So, I want more details about this method.

Thanks.

Comment: Why would you ask how to do something, and then post a link that is demonstrating how to do it?

Comment: This article is still available at http://web.archive.org/web/20110812164932/http://blog.triphp.com/lessons/htaccess/automatic-chmod .  It provides no documentation on how the mentioned feature works, none could be found, and for me the feature did not work.  Hence, this is a valid, but poorly phrased, question.

Answer (score 1):

I believe the article lies, and there is no such feature for htaccess files.

I could not find a reference to this directive in the apache documentation or source code.

Comment: Downvoters, when I posted this, it was true.  Why the downvote?